# mapstructure decode a map[string]interface{} into a struct containing custom type gives Error

Tags: go, unmarshalling

My app takes a JSON string, unmarshal into a struct `BiggerType` and then, using [mapstructure](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) to decode the struct's field `Settings` into a type `MainType`. `BiggerType` needs to support multiple types of `Settings` and hence, is and **has to be** declared as `map[string]interface{}`. The app used to be working fine until we have a new type of `Settings`, i.e. `MainType` containing some custom fields with the type `SpecialType`.

The structs and the main codes are included below. Running the code gives the following error.

```
* 'b' expected a map, got 'string'
```

*Some codes were removed for brevity*

```
package main

import (
    ...
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

const myJSON = `{
  "settings": {
    "a": {
      "aa": {
        "aaa": {
          "sta": "special_object_A",
          "stb": "special_object_B"
        },
        "aab": "bab"
      },
      "ab": true
    },
    "b": "special_string"
  },
  "other": "other"
}`

func main() {
    var biggerType BiggerType

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(myJSON), &biggerType)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var decodedMainType MainType

    if err := mapstructure.Decode(biggerType.Settings, &decodedMainType); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}

type BiggerType struct {
    Other    string   `json:"other"`
    // Settings MainType `json:"settings"` can't be used as it needs to support other "Settings"
    Settings map[string]interface{} `json:"settings"`
}

type A struct {
    Aa *AA   `json:"aa"`
    Ab *bool `json:"ab"`
}

type AA struct {
    Aaa SpecialType `json:"aaa"`
    Aab string      `json:"aab"`
}

type MainType struct {
    A A           `json:"a"`
    B SpecialType `json:"b"`
}

type SpecialTypeObject struct {
    Sta string `json:"sta"`
    Stb string `json:"stb"`
}

func (s SpecialTypeObject) InterfaceMethod() (string, error) {
    return s.Sta + "+" + s.Stb, nil
}

type SpecialTypeString string

func (s SpecialTypeString) InterfaceMethod() (string, error) {
    return string(s), nil
}

type SpecialInterface interface {
    InterfaceMethod() (string, error)
}

// SpecialType SpecialTypeString | SpecialTypeObject
type SpecialType struct {
    Value SpecialInterface
}

func (s *SpecialType) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    ...
}
```

My goal is to be able to decode `biggerType.Settings` into `decodedMainType` with all the values intact. Can anyone please share with me any workaround or/and suggestions?

The playground to replicate the issue: https://go.dev/play/p/G6mdnVoE2vZ

Thank you.

Comment: Use `interface{}` instead of `map[string]interface{}`.

Comment: Using `interface{}` gives the same error as shown in https://go.dev/play/p/Z0EqluGp3gz

Comment: Ignore me, I didn't notice you rely on some 3rd party package.

Comment: You may want to re-phrase at least the title if not the whole question, that the problem you have is not with JSON but with how to use the 3rd party package called `mapstructure`.

Comment: Changed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In fact, this has nothing to do with JSON.   Really, your question is about how to turn an interface under `BiggerType.Settings` into a `SpecialType` that holds either a `SpecialTypeString` or a `SpecialTypeObject`.  Bringing `mapstructure` into it is a bit of an XY problem .  https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Your question hinges on 2 alternative values for settings.  But much of your code seems to be built around handling a special value under `settings.B`.  Can you show an example of settings with `settings.B` not a string and how you want the results to look?

Comment: I'd recommend to unlearn using the word "type" when naming _variables:_ it impedes reading. Of course, this might be just an artefact of you preparing the MCVE; if so, please ignore my hint ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm with Daniel Farrell on this, but it's possible to fix the existing solution.

The idea is to make use of the `mapstructure`'s ability to customize its `Decoder` which can take a "hook" which is called at key points during the decoding process. There are multiple available hooks and they can be combined into a "chain-style" hook.

Since there's a stock hook which is able to check whether the target variable's type implements `encoding.TextUnmarshaler`, we can tweak your `(*SpecialType).UnmarshalJSON` to become `(*SpecialType).UnmarshalText` and then use that:

```golang
func (s *SpecialType) UnmarshalText(data []byte) error {
    if len(data) > 0 && data[0] != '{' {
        s.Value = SpecialTypeString(data)
        return nil
    }

    var obj SpecialTypeObject
    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &obj); err != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("failed to unmarshal SpecialType: %s", err)
    }
    s.Value = obj
    return nil
}
```

and

```golang
var decodedMainType MainType

msd, err := mapstructure.NewDecoder(&mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
    DecodeHook: mapstructure.TextUnmarshallerHookFunc(),
    Result:     &decodedMainType,
})
if err != nil {
    return BiggerType{}, err
}

if err := msd.Decode(biggerType.Settings); err != nil {
    return BiggerType{}, err
}
```

The complete solution: https://go.dev/play/p/jaCD9FdSECz.

But then again — as Daniel hinted at, you appear to have fallen for using `mapstructure` because it promised to be a no-brainer solution for a problem which appeared to be complicated.
In fact, `encoding/json` appears to have stock facilities to cover your use case — exactly through making certain types implement `json.Unmarshaler`, so I'd try to ditch `mapstructure` for this case: it's a useful package, but now you appear to be working around the rules of the framework it implements.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why it doesn't work

> `* 'b' expected a map, got 'string'`

In the JSON, `settings.b` is a string type.  You've decoded it into a `BiggerType` in which settings is a `map[string]interface{}`. The standard library provided JSON Unmarshalling process results in a map like:

```
map[string]interface{} {
   "A": map[string]interface{}{...},
   "B": string("special_value"),
}
```

JSON decoding is now done. No more Json decoding happens in the program.

You then attempt to use `mapstructure` to Decode your `settings` `map` into a `MainType`, where `B` is of type `SettingsType`.    So `mapstructure.Decode` dutifully iterates over your `BiggerType` and attempts to turn it into a `MainType`, but hits a snag.  when it gets to `B`, the input is a string, and the output is a `SettingsType`.

You wrote an `UnmarshalJSON` function for settings type, but `B`'s value is not being unmarshalled from JSON - it's already a string.  Decode doesn't know how to turn a `string` into a `SpecialType` ( it says it expected a  `map` but that's a little misleading as [it actually checks for map, struct, slice, and array types](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure/blob/master/mapstructure.go#L812))

###### Rephrasing the problem you're facing

So then let's identify the error a little more specifically: You have. `map[string]interface{}` with a string value, `mapstructure.Decode` tries to decode it into a struct field with a Struct value.

#### Rephrasing the goal

Everything you've shown here is issues you're facing with your solution.  What is your underlying problem?  You have an `interface{}` in `BiggerType.Settings` that might be a `string` and might be a `map[string]interface{}`, and you want to turn it into a `SpecialType` that holds either a `SpecialTypeString` or a `SpecialTypeObj`

I can't entirely square that with your question though, where you keep talking about `MainType` being possibly different types, but all the different types in your program seem to be under `SpecialType`.

#### How to Solve

It seems like the obvious solution here is to ditch `mapstructure` and use the method you already use for `SpecialType` with a custom unmarshaller.  `mapstructure` is useful for cases when you need to unmarshal JSON to introspect some attributes and then make a decision about how to handle other attributes.  You're not doing anything like that with `mapstructure` though; the closest thing is your custom unmarshaller.  If a custom Unmarshaller can do the job, you don't need `mapstructure`.

`SpecialType.UnmarshalJSON` in your code is already an example of how you could wrap an unknown value in a known type and use a `switch` statement to handle unknown value types.

So just ditch `mapstructure`, redefine `BiggerType` as:

```
type BiggerType struct {
    Other    string   `json:"other"`
    Settings MainType `json:"settings"`
}
```

And let the already-written `UnmarshalJSON` handle `MainType.B`.

If it's not `SpecialType` that needs this logic, but `MainType`, then do the same thing with `SpecialType` that you did to `MainType`.

https://go.dev/play/p/DW8N8t3Lr0l

If you want to see a solution with `mapstructure`, please provide more than one example of the JSON input so I can see how they differ and why `mapstructure` might be required.